# Text in CKEDITOR field not being submitted in the first submission

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

**The text in `ckeditor` field is not sent when submitting forms for the first time (only on the second time, third time, etc).**

For example, If try to create an article's post and submit the form I'll get a validation error: 'The field `body` is required'. If try to submit again (for the second time or third time), It will work well.

**The real problem is when editing!** For example, when editing a form the field 'body', among others fields, is filled out with the data from the database. In other words, there are already text in the ckeditor field.

If I try to submit the form for the first time **it will not update the `body` because the text in the `ckeditor` is not sent; what is sent is the default value** (the old article's `body`, which was filled out with data from the DB).

Therefore, it won't edit unless I get a validation error in other field (if I get a validation error, I'll have to submit again, and that will work).

How to solve this problem? Is this an known bug in `CKEDITOR` 4? If I don't solve it the users will feel frustrated if they have to submit the form at least twice to edit or to create an article.

Here is a list of plugins I'm using (may be useful to solve the problem):

a11yhelp, about, api, autocomplete, autocorrect, browser, clipboard, colordialog, copyformatting, crossereference, dialog, div, docprops, find, googlesearch, image, link, liststyle, magicline, mathjax, openlink, pastecode, pastefromword, preview, quicktable, scayt, section, showblocks, sourcedialog, specialchar, table, tableselection, tabletools, tabletoolstoolbar, texttransform, widget, wsc

By the way, I downloaded `ckeditor` using `ckeditor` builder in their official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened this issue in GitHub and a guy figured out the problem. His proposed solution worked wel!! Here is what he said:

> **Workaround**
>
> As the issue is more tricky to fix than it seems, for now I propose a
>   simple workaround: invoke `ajaxRequest` not on `$( document ).ready`,
>   but rather on editor's loaded event:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
  on: { 
         loaded: function() {ajaxRequest();}
      }
  });
```

> **Explanation of the issue**
>
> The issue is connected with how DOM listeners are registered for given
>   element:
>
> The order of event listeners for a particular event type will always
>   be:
>
> - The event listeners registered with `addEventListener()` before the    first time the event handler's value was set to non-null
> - Then the callback to which it is currently set, if any
> - Finally, the event listeners registered with `addEventListener()`    after the first time the event handler's value was set to non-null.
>
> In case of CKEditor 4, the value of the form's element is modified by
>   editor._attachToForm private method, which adds event listener to
>   form's submit event:
>
> `ckeditor-dev/core/editor.js` `form.on( 'submit', onSubmit );`
>
> However this listener is added on loaded event, which is fired
>   asynchronously when editor is loaded – so after registering
>   synchronous onsubmit handler with the validation logic. This way
>   editor's field is updated after validating.
>
> **Proposed solutions**
>
> Update editor's element on `formdata` event. This way we would have
>   total control over data being submitted and we would be sure that
>   correct data is set before submit event. The problem with this
>   solution is the fact that browsers' support is non-existent; the event
>   will appear in Chrome 77, however it is still not known if and when
>   the support will appear in Firefox or Safari.
>
> Update editor's element on every change in the editor's content thanks
>   to change event. This solution will also fix cases, where some other
>   scripts are using value not from the editor, but directly from the
>   replaced `textarea` – they would get fresh data more often then only
>   after submitting the form. However this solution requires #1364, which
>   connects with a pretty big refactoring.

**NOTE**: `AjaxRequest` is the function I was using to submit the form togehter with `Jquery`.